# Show data from 2 tables + zend framework

Tags: php, sql, arrays, zend-framework, html-table

I want to show data from my database into my table in html. (when i click on a link)

Table "births" fields:

- district
- year1999
- year2000
- year2001
- year2002
- year2003
- year2004
- year2005
- year2006
- year2007
- year2008
- year2009

Table "deaths" fields:

- district
- year1999
- year2000
- year2001
- year2002
- year2003
- year2004
- year2005
- year2006
- year2007
- year2008
- year2009

I will get the data from my database true an ajax call in javascript. I link to an action in my indexcontroller.

Javascript code:

```
$("#wijken ul li a").click(function(e){

        district = ($(this).text());

        loadTable(district);

      });

function loadTable(district){
    var param1 = district;

    $.ajax({ 
      url: 'index/getdata',         
      type: "POST",             
      data: {param1: param1},                        
      dataType: 'json',                
      success: function(result)          
      {
        var htmlContent = "";

       // HOW CAN I PARSE THE DATA?

        htmlContent += '</tbody></table>';
        $('#tabel').html(htmlContent);

      }, 
      error: function(request, status, error){
          alert(request.responseText);
      }
    });
}
```

My IndexController:

```
public function getdataAction()
    {
        // DISABLE VIEW
        $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

        // WIJK CLICKED
        $district = $this->_request->getParam('param1');

        // GET THE BIRTHS/YEAR
        $birthMapper = new Frontoffice_Model_BirthMapper();
        $array = $birthMapper->read($district);

        $this->_response->setBody(json_encode($array));
    }
```

My BirthMapper:

```
public function read($wijk = null)
    {
        $table = $this->_dbTable;

        $columns = array('wijk'         => 'wijk',
                         'year1999'     => 'year1999',
                         'year2000'     => 'year2000',
                         'year2001'     => 'year2001',
                         'year2002'     => 'year2002',
                         'year2003'     => 'year2003',
                         'year2004'     => 'year2004',
                         'year2005'     => 'year2005',
                         'year2006'     => 'year2006',
                         'year2007'     => 'year2007',
                         'year2008'     => 'year2008',
                         'year2009'     => 'year2009',
        );

        $select = $table->select()
                        ->from($table,
                               $columns
                          )
                        ->where('wijk = :wijk')
                        ->bind(array(':wijk' => $wijk))

         ;

        if ($row = $table->fetchRow($select)) {
           return $row->toArray();
       }


        throw  new Exception('The requested Births cannot be found');
    }
```

Now I can handle the year1999,year2000,year2001,year2002,year2003,year2004,year2005,year2006,year2007,year2008,year2009 fields in my javascript as result.year1999. But how can I do this for multiple tables? (In javascript and controller)

Comment: keeping every year in different column is crazy stuff, consider to do it right maybe

Comment: I load data from json to my db. In json its also year_1999, year_2000 .. Thats the reason

Comment: consider about converting it :)

Comment: no way that I can do this without converting?

Comment: i am just talking about proper practice, not your question :)

Comment: @user1775531 it is not clear what do you mean by "But how can I do **this** for multiple tables?" What is **this**? What is the problem, i.e. what do you want to have? You need to convert json response into table, don`t you?